# Tunnel closed. packet_write_wait: Connection to UNKNOWN port 0: Broken pipe

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

Hello community for several days I am having problems to keep connected to a **ssh tunnel** that I perform to a VPS. After 2 to 4 minutes, I get this error: **Tunnel closed. packet_write_wait: Connection to UNKNOWN port 0: Broken pipe**. I have been reading in forums but I still can not find a solution, these are my configuration files. **It is worth mentioning that I access the internet through a proxy (Squid).**

On my **SSH server** (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) add this lines:

```
ClientAliveInterval 60
ClientAliveCountMax 5
TCPKeepAlive no
```

On my **SSH client** (~/.ssh/config):

```
Host myhost
    User root
    ProxyCommand proxytunnel -p proxy.example.com:3128 -P userproxy:passwordproxy -d dominiovps.com:443 -v -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Win32)" 
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ServerAliveCountMax 5
    TCPKeepAlive no
```

Comment: looks like a problem somewhere on the way, closing you the connections. Setting `TCPKeepAlive yes` is worth trying.

Comment: I have configured `TCPKeepAlive yes` it on the server and on the client but it still keeps disconnecting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to decrease `ServerAliveInterval` to `15` or `20`: looks like your proxy server is configured for timeout lower than `60` and closes your connection after some idle interval.

Comment: I have configured `ServerAliveInterval` to `20, 15 and 10` it on the server and on the client but it still keeps disconnecting me.